# Why do I keep getting TypeError even though input is an interger?

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm coding something for a school project which asks the user for a number between 0-10 and I have no idea why I keep getting a TypeError even though the input is converted to integer using a list. Any help please? I'm doing this on Wing IDE 101.

```
numbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
while True:
    num = ''
    while num == '':
        try:
            num = input("Please enter a number: ")
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            if num in numbers:
                num = numbers.index(num)
                num = int(num)
            else:
                print('Invalid input, please enter valid input')
    if num == 0:
        print("Thank you for using this program")
        break
    elif num < 0 or num > 10:
        print("This is an invalid number, please enter a valid number.")
        print()
        continue
```

Comment: You are simply doing `bool(TypeError)` which is `True` regardless of `num` or whatever the condition you are expecting. What is the purpose of `if TypeError`?

Comment: If you want to check for `TypeError` use within `except`, eg. `except ValueError, TypeError: do_something`

Comment: The if TypeError is just used to check if there is one. Although it can just be removed. Also if the if TypeError and elif num < 0 or num >10 is removed the code works.

Comment: `if TypeError` does not check whether a `TypeError` occurred, it checks whether the object `TypeError` evaluates to `True` or not, which it always will, your condition basically means whether `TypeError` is a thing in python.

Comment: @SayandipDutta if you remove the if TypeError which I just added in for seemingly no reason you get `elif num < 0 or num > 10:
builtins.TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' ` and I have no idea why.

Comment: @Chris The if TypeError is useless

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: After `print('Invalid input, please enter valid input')`, add `num=''`. Otherwise, any invalid number will just be passed onto `elif num < 0 or num > 10:` and cause an error.

Comment: @SayandipDutta I think this may be a Wing IDE 101 specific thing so if you want to replicate it you have to download Wing IDE 101.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this the reason:

When your input is not a valid input like `"asdf"`. It will jump out the inner while loop. Because you inner while loop condition is `num == ''` while `num` is `"asdf"` now.

You should just put `num = ""` under `print('Invalid input, please enter valid input')` and your code will work and not raise TypeError anymore.

Complete code below:

```
numbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
while True:
    num = ''
    while num == '':
        try:
            num = input("Please enter a number: ")
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            if num in numbers:
                num = numbers.index(num)
                num = int(num)
            else:
                print('Invalid input, please enter valid input')
                num = ""
    if num == 0:
        print("Thank you for using this program")
        break
    elif num < 0 or num > 10:
        print("This is an invalid number, please enter a valid number.")
        print()
        continue
```

In fact your code could be simpfy to one loop:

```
numbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
while True:
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if num in numbers:
        num = numbers.index(num)
    else:
        try:
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input, please enter valid input")
            continue
    if num == 0:
        print("Thank you for using this program")
        break
    elif num < 0 or num > 10:
        print("This is an invalid number, please enter a valid number.")
```

Comment: ```numbers.index(num)``` already is an integer, so no need to ```int(num)``` in the next line.

Comment: I just copy all the code in the question and insert the num = "" to make Flameboy0501 understand this easier. But I think you are right. Would change the answer.

Comment: Quishi  my apologies..  thought I was quoting the OP.

Comment: Thanks @XuQiushi, Chris already pointed out that I should add num = '' at the end of the else but this simplified loop is helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to you can happen a lot in dynamic language since the types are resolved on runtime rather on design time, so sometimes it is hard to figure.

First, separate the `user_input` from the number (`num`) you are evaluating, into 2 different parameters (one for user input string and one for integer) - I know it does not matter on Python, but it is a good practice.

Now your `num` value will only be assigned on a successful parsing. No need for `continue` at the end of the loop as well

**Code Snippet**

```
numbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
while True:
    user_input = ''
    num = None  # default invalid value
    while num is None:
        try:
            user_input = input("Please enter a number: ")
            num = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            if user_input in numbers:
                num = numbers.index(user_input)
            else:
                print('Invalid input, please enter valid input')
                print()
    if num == 0:
        print("Thank you for using this program")
        break
    elif num < 0 or num > 10:
        print("This is an invalid number, please enter a valid number.")
        print()
```

**Debug Output**

```
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: one
Please enter a number: 11
This is an invalid number, please enter a valid number.

Please enter a number: -1
This is an invalid number, please enter a valid number.

Please enter a number: no numbder
Invalid input, please enter valid input

Please enter a number: 0
Thank you for using this program

Process finished with exit code 0
```